# Safari starts automatically after login

Tags: macos, login, login-items

Since a few days, after every boot Safari will automatically start. Today, the same thing happens with OmniOutliner Pro (MAS Version). I have the latest version of OS X 10.9.3 (13D65)

These programs aren't listed in Login Items. "Reopening windows when logging back in" is deactivated.

The following Login Items exist:

- TextExpander
- Divvy
- Dropbox
- HazelHelper
- Fantastical
- Launchbar
- Jitouch

This is my console log right after boot, contain the strings

*Safari*

```
25.06.14 15:21:45,390 WindowServer[101]: disable_update_timeout: UI updates were forcibly disabled by application "Safari" for over 1.00 seconds. Server has re-enabled them.
25.06.14 15:21:45,576 WindowServer[101]: common_reenable_update: UI updates were finally reenabled by application "Safari" after 1.19 seconds (server forcibly re-enabled them after 1.00 seconds)
25.06.14 15:21:48,358 2BUA8C4S2C.com.agilebits.onepassword-osx-helper[185]: 441006 [EXT:0x7fa0915bb9a0:<OP4ExtensionHTTPConnection: 0x7fa09174f530>] M webSocketForURI: | [ES4] Extension connected Safari-Extension 'safari-extension://com.agilebits.onepassword4-safari-2bua8c4s2c / (null)'
```

*OmniOutliner*

```
25.06.14 15:21:47,964 OmniOutliner[310]: OBFinishPortingLater at /Volumes/Local/Shared/omnibuild/ReleaseProduct/Source/OmniGroup/Applications/OmniOutliner/OutlineView/OOOutlineRow-Private.m:838 in -[OOOutlineRow(Private) _layoutChildrenInView:yPosition:]
25.06.14 15:21:47,964 OmniOutliner[310]: OBFinishPortingLater at /Volumes/Local/Shared/omnibuild/ReleaseProduct/Source/OmniGroup/Applications/OmniOutliner/OutlineView/OOOutlineRow-Drawing.m:62 in -[OOOutlineRow(Drawing) laidRowAtYOffset:height:inView:]
25.06.14 15:21:49,534 sandboxd[305]: ([310]) OmniOutliner(310) deny job-creation
```

What can I do to prevent this to happen?

Comment: Tell us which other programs are listed in Login items. Maybe one of them needs Safari!

Comment: What happens when you press and hold Shift immediately after logging in? Holding Shift logs you in in a safe mode environment, and disables all startup items.

Comment: I am to lazy to create an answer, but you might try the following. Replace /Application/Sarafi/Contents/MacOS/Sarari with the following script: #!/bin/bash echo $$ >>~/safari.log.txt to capture the PID that calls for Safari. It might take you further in debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out, why this happens. It’s a new Launchbar 6 Extension, which allows me to send all open Safari Tabs to OmniOutliner. Unfortunately it starts both apps with every start of Launchbar

Answer (score 5):

Despite these programs aren't listed in Login Items I'd recommend you to check again the state of "Open at Login" option in the dock.[image: The Dock]

Next stop is to verify the content of these folders

```
~/Library/LaunchAgents

/Library/LaunchAgents
/System/Library/LaunchAgents
```

Launch Agents are usually loaded by `launchd` when the user logs in

Comment: If 'Open at Login' is checked, it is also listed in the 'Startup Items'. The OP says it is not.

Comment: @CousinCocaine right, this is a double-check :-) The important part of the answer is the **Next stop**

Answer (score 0):

If it was only one application (safari) I would say it is you, but with second one now doing it,sounds like your User profile can use some repairing.

Repair your User Profile:

Start by booting from the Recovery HD partition. You can do this by restarting your Mac while holding down the <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd> keys. Keep holding the two keys until you see the Recovery HD desktop appear.

You will see the OS X Utilities window open on your desktop, with various options available in its window. You can ignore this window; there's nothing we need to do with it.

Instead, select Terminal from the Utilities menu at the top of the screen.In the Terminal window that opens, enter the following:

```
    resetpassword
```

Press enter or return.

The Reset Password window will open.

Make sure the Reset Password window is the front-most window.

From the Utilities menu, select Reset Password.

In the Reset Password window that opens, select the drive that contains your home folder; this is usually your Mac's startup drive.

Use the drop-down menu to select the user account whose home folder permissions you wish to fix.

**Do not** enter any password information.

**DO NOT** click the Save button.

Instead, click the Reset button located just below the "Reset Home Folder Permissions and ACLs" text.

The process may take a while, depending on the size of the home folder. Eventually the Reset button will change to say Done.

Quit the Reset Password utility by selecting Quit from the Reset Password menu.

Quit the OS X Installer by selecting Quit Mac OS X Installer from the Mac OS X Installer menu.

Click the Restart button.

```
Once you quit the Reset Password app, be sure to quit the Terminal app by selecting Quit Terminal from the Terminal menu.

From the OS X Utilities menu, select Quit OS X Utilities.

You'll be asked if you really want to exit OS X Utilities; click the Restart button.
```

That's all there is to resetting your user account's file permissions back to the correct default settings. At this point, you can use your Mac as you normally would. The problems you were experiencing should be gone.

[Source](http://macs.about.com/od/Troubleshooting/qt/Mac-Troubleshooting-Reset-User-Account-Permissions.htm)

Comment: I reseted the ALC permissions, but the problem persists.